# Delphi 2010 - Triggering actions accurately in realtime

Tags: delphi, timer

My first question - apologies if it is not specific enough!

I volunteered to write an app in Delphi for local sailing club. This fires various (RS232 commands) lights + Klaxon starting signals every 3 minutes, whole sequence can take 24 minutes. Since sailors set stopwatches this must be much better than 1 second over 24 minutes.

I have a threaded timer component which IS accurate, and in `Timer.Execute` proc I need to update GUI etc - this is giving freezes/crashes etc. What is better way to do this?

I think I should not be changing GUI objects in the execute, but how to get around it? (I am not very familiar with threads). Many thanks for you advice. Any further info needed I'm happy to give.

Chris

Addition - the CairnTimer class
`code`

```
unit CairnTimer;
interface
uses
  Windows,SysUtils,Classes,Dialogs;
type
  TCairnTimer=class(TComponent)
  private
    TimerOn:             Boolean;
    TimerThreadPriority: TThreadPriority;
    TimerPaused:         Boolean;
    TimerDelay:          Cardinal;
    TimerResolution:     Cardinal;
    TimerTicks:          Cardinal;
    TimerMilliSeconds:   Cardinal;
    OnTimerEvent:        TNotifyEvent;
    OnTimerEventHandle:  Integer;
    TimerName:           Integer;
  protected
    procedure InitTimer;
    procedure SetTimerTicks(NewTicks: Cardinal);
    procedure UpdateTimerStatus(NewOn: Boolean);
    procedure UpdateTimerPriority(NewPriority: TThreadPriority);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Resume;
    procedure Pause;
    property Ticks: Cardinal read TimerTicks default 0;
    property MilliSeconds: Cardinal read TimerMilliSeconds default 0;
  published
    property Enabled: Boolean read TimerOn write UpdateTimerStatus default False;
    property TimerPriority: TThreadPriority read TimerThreadPriority write UpdateTimerPriority default tpNormal;
    property Delay: Cardinal read TimerDelay write TimerDelay default 100;
    property Resolution: Cardinal read TimerResolution write TimerResolution default 10;
    property OnTimer: TNotifyEvent read OnTimerEvent write OnTimerEvent;
  end;

  TCairnTimerThread=class(TThread)
  public
    CairnTimer: TCairnTimer;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;
  TCairnTimerCallBack=procedure(NA1,NA2,CairnTimerUser,NA3,NA4: Integer) stdcall;
  ECairnTimer=class(Exception);

var
  CairnTimerThread: TCairnTimerThread;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('System',[TCairnTimer]);
end;

function KillTimer(CairnTimerName: Integer): Integer;stdcall;
           external 'WinMM.dll' name 'timeKillEvent';

function SetTimer(TimerDelay,TimerResolution: Integer;
          CairnTimerCallBack: TCairnTimerCallBack;
          CairnTimerUser,CairnTimerFlags: Integer): Integer;stdcall;
          external 'WinMM.dll' name 'timeSetEvent';

procedure TCairnTimerThread.Execute;
var
  TickRecord: Cardinal;
begin
  TickRecord:=0;
  while not(Terminated)and Assigned(CairnTimer)do
  begin
    WaitForSingleObject(CairnTimer.OnTimerEventHandle,INFINITE);
    Inc(TickRecord);
    CairnTimer.SetTimerTicks(TickRecord);
    if Assigned(CairnTimer.OnTimerEvent)then
      CairnTimer.OnTimerEvent(CairnTimer);
  end;
end;

constructor TCairnTimer.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  TimerOn:=False;
  TimerDelay:=100;
  TimerResolution:=10;
  TimerPaused:=False;
  TimerTicks:=0;
  TimerMilliSeconds:=0;
  TimerThreadPriority:=tpNormal;
  OnTimerEventHandle:=CreateEvent(nil,False,False,nil);
end;

destructor TCairnTimer.Destroy;
begin
  Enabled:=False;
  CloseHandle(OnTimerEventHandle);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TCairnTimer.SetTimerTicks(NewTicks: Cardinal);
begin
  TimerTicks:=NewTicks;
  TimerMilliSeconds:=TimerMilliSeconds+TimerDelay;
end;

procedure CairnTimerCallBack(NA1,NA2,CairnTimerUser,NA3,NA4: Integer); stdcall;
var
  CairnTimer: TCairnTimer;
begin
  CairnTimer:=TCairnTimer(CairnTimerUser);
  if Assigned(CairnTimer) then
    if not CairnTimer.TimerPaused then
      SetEvent(CairnTimer.OnTimerEventHandle);
end;

procedure TCairnTimer.InitTimer;
begin
  TimerName:=SetTimer(TimerDelay,TimerResolution,@CairnTimerCallBack,Integer(Self),1);
  if TimerName=0 then
  begin
    TimerOn:=False;
    raise ECairnTimer.Create('Cairn timer creation error.');
  end;
end;

procedure TCairnTimer.UpdateTimerStatus(NewOn: Boolean);
begin
  if NewOn=TimerOn then Exit;
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
  begin
    TimerOn:=NewOn;
    Exit;
  end;
  if(NewOn)then
  begin
    CairnTimerThread:=TCairnTimerThread.Create(True);
    CairnTimerThread.CairnTimer:=Self;
    CairnTimerThread.FreeOnTerminate:=True;
    CairnTimerThread.Priority:=TimerThreadPriority;
    CairnTimerThread.CairnTimer.InitTimer;
    CairnTimerThread.Resume;
    TimerTicks:=0;
    TimerMilliSeconds:=0;
  end;
  if(not(NewOn))then
  begin
    KillTimer(TimerName);
    TerminateThread(CairnTimerThread.Handle,0);
    CairnTimerThread.Free;
  end;
  TimerOn:=NewOn;
end;

procedure TCairnTimer.UpdateTimerPriority(NewPriority: TThreadPriority);
begin
  if NewPriority=TimerThreadPriority then Exit;
  if Assigned(CairnTimerThread) then
  begin
    CairnTimerThread.Priority:=NewPriority;
  end;
  TimerThreadPriority:=NewPriority;
end;

procedure TCairnTimer.Pause;
begin
  if TimerOn then CairnTimerThread.Suspend;
  TimerPaused:=True;
end;

procedure TCairnTimer.Resume;
begin
  if TimerOn then CairnTimerThread.Resume;
  TimerPaused:=False;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's very difficult to say what you might be doing wrong without any code to show what you're doing. What threaded timer are you using? Are you updating the GUI using `Synchronize`? If not, how are you trying to update it? Please edit your question to provide more information (preferably in the form of some code) so it's more clear what you're currently doing. (Also, `freezes/crashes/etc.` is a pretty meaningless description of errors or problems; it doesn't give much info to go on either.)

Comment: Maybe one of the questions from the [*\[delphi\] update gui thread*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+update+gui+thread) search has some useful information for you.

Comment: I am using a freeware component called CairnTimer. I am not using synchronise. The threaded timer execute looks like this:

Comment: procedure TCairnTimerThread.Execute;
var
  TickRecord: Cardinal;
begin
  TickRecord:=0;
  while not(Terminated)and Assigned(CairnTimer)do
  begin
    WaitForSingleObject(CairnTimer.OnTimerEventHandle,INFINITE);
    Inc(TickRecord);
    CairnTimer.SetTimerTicks(TickRecord);
    if Assigned(CairnTimer.OnTimerEvent)then
      CairnTimer.OnTimerEvent(CairnTimer);
  end;
end;

Comment: Why do you need to do this with threads? I can't see how they help. On the contrary, threads would likely just complicate matters

Comment: I'll restate my answer below - a bigger source of error is your PC clock, not thread synchronisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update VCL controls from another thread , you have synchronise and pass a method of your thread to it.

```
procedure TMyThread.DoProgress;
 var
   PctDone: Extended;
 begin
   PctDone := (FCounter / FCountTo) ;
   FProgressBar.Position := Round(FProgressBar.Step * PctDone) ;
   FOwnerButton.Caption := FormatFloat('0.00 %', PctDone * 100) ;
 end;

 procedure TMyThread.Execute;
 const
   Interval = 1000000;
 begin
   FreeOnTerminate := True;
   FProgressBar.Max := FCountTo div Interval;
   FProgressBar.Step := FProgressBar.Max;

   while FCounter < FCountTo do
   begin
     if FCounter mod Interval = 0 then Synchronize(DoProgress) ;

     Inc(FCounter) ;
   end;

   FOwnerButton.Caption := 'Start';
   FOwnerButton.OwnedThread := nil;
   FProgressBar.Position := FProgressBar.Max;
 end;
```

Never liked this one myself, too tightly coupled.

If I was doing this with threads, I think I'd be using a shared memory manouevre or if it was simple just a few windows messages.

It is the thread that's doing the comms for the light and horns???

Comment: I am using TMS Async comonent to send the RS232 commands, but calling it from within the timer.OnTimer execute proc. If I can work out how to post the timer code I will do so! (help!!)

Comment: @Ken have posted code as addition to original question, many thanks to all for your help so far

Comment: Too much other stuff that could be causing problems here. If I were you I'd get it working from the main thread with a straight TTimer component. As long as your main thread isn't busy with something else it should easily process the OnTimer event within a second. One you'gve got that working (given you write modular code), you can look at threading it, though like @Andrew Hefferenan, I can't see any particular reason to do so. Tip one for multi threading, make sure what you want to thread works.

Comment: with a TTimer my app seems to be ok! (tho not accurate of course). So I wonder, does the Notify event in the code mean that CairnTimer.OnTimer() where I have my code, is running in the Timer thread or in the main VCL thread? Should I simply update a global variable (in a critical section?) and then use a separate TTimer to "poll" this at say 0.2 sec intervals for a change, and update GUI etc from that (i.e. in the main thread) What do you think?

Comment: The thread raised the event, so any code in an event handler is also in the thread. That's why you need things like synchronise or handovers. Your last idea would work, as long as the timer is running in the main thread. Windows m,essages would take explicit need for polling out though.

Comment: Just to belatedly update this thread, I solved the issue using the CairnTimer component I mentioned above, BUT just used the timer component execute() to push a custom windows message into the queue. (I pick that up in the main thread and drive code there to sound klaxon.lights etc. This has proved a very good solution. 
The overall effect is that the timer remains perfectly accurate over 30 minutes (to better than 1/4 sec). Only wrinkle is that any individual action may (does) vary a very small amount due to delays in the message queue, but this is not significant. Thanks to all!

Answer (score -1):

If you want sub-second accuracy over a lengthy period of time you need to ensure that your PC clock is accurate. I have seen PC clocks that can drift a couple of seconds over an hour, so a completely accurate timer will still not suffice. To do this I synchronise my PC/laptop clocks with an NTP server every minute (taking the median/average of about 20 requests). A good server/PC/laptop can thus be kept within a few miliiseconds of an accurate reference time all the time.

Comment: -1. This has nothing to do with the question asked, which clearly says `I have a threaded timer component which IS accurate`.

Comment: @Ken, accurate to what, the PC, or an NTP server? Have you asked? I will quite happily accept a down vote to post what I think is useful information.

Comment: @Ken, I suggest you read http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vcgeneral/thread/81f70af1-a6a0-4345-a248-c93b3370fd9a (all about SetTimer() and PC clock accuracy problems)

Comment: Guy's use a stop watch. Klaxon to Klaxon presumably, so this duration timing, not do this at 15:08 GMT precisely

Comment: @Tony, durations are affected by PC clock drift as well. If the clock drifts 3 seconds in 1 hour, then over 24 minutes the duration will be out by over a second. Keeping the PC/laptop in sync ensures that you can keep the duration to close to millisecond accuracy. I do this by sleeping till a set time (with sync'd clock) and checking every 100 milliseconds or so. When under 100 milliseconds you sleep for the amount of time left. In this way I can have a timer span several days and be accurate to within a few millisconds.

Comment: @Misha Hi Misha, all you say about pc clock accuracy is true. This is why the CairnTimer uses the multimedia system. This is driven by a hardware crystal, so is not related to the pc clock.It is very stable and accurate. As a practical test I have timed it on several different pc's for one hour, against a stop watch, and it stays rock solid.

Comment: @ChrisH, I'm not sure that you are correct here. The calibration of the timers is not that accurate - it can be, but there is no guarantee. Do a test for me and see how accurate it is over 24 hours on a couple of PCs against a clock sync'd to a NTP server. BTW, the CairnTimer does not use the multimedia timer - SetTimer() is not the multimedia timer.

Comment: @ChrisH, have a look at this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644900%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which states "a timer's accuracy depends on the system clock rate". Sorry to go on about this, but close to millisecond timing accuracy was a pet project of mine a while ago.

Comment: Where did you get hold of this hardware crystal? Is it connected to the PC by USB or something?

Comment: @Misha I take your point about the SetTimer() function - I am under the impression (might be wrong!) that the code for CairnTimer actually (re)defines the SetTimer and KillTimer() functions and the call is to the MultiMedia system:

Comment: @David I was referring to the sound system hardware - the AC97 standard, (but you are right, it can be a crystal, but does not have to be!). The 40pin chip contains a clock that runs at 12.2MHz afair, and is divided down to give 44.1/48KHz reference for digital sound. I was also assuming that timing derived from this would be used by Windows when getting MM times - a lot of assumptions I agree!

Comment: @ChrisH, you are right, SetTimer() here redefines access to the timeSetEvent() function. That is truly horrible, to redefine a standard Windows API function to "point" to another one with a different name.

Comment: Well, just to finish this thread off (pun intended!) I finished the app and it has been running for 2 years now. The accuracy is excellent using the Cairn timer. No drift at all. Remember that I am interested ONLY in relative time since a race started, so not bothered about real time of day accuracy.